# What do they mean by a pendulum losing seconds?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

In many pendulum related question, a pendulum is taken do a different place where it **loses seconds**. For example:

> A second's pendulum is taken to a mountain and it loses 20 seconds per day. What
>   is the height of the mountain? (the radius of the earth is 6400km)

My problem: If the pendulum has a time period of 2 seconds, how can it lose 20 seconds? And why would it lose seconds?

I know this question is really elementary but I am really confused

Comment: You are right, whoever likes to ask these kinds o questions is a bit lost between physics and English.

Comment: It seems rather ambiguous, maybe would be better if you post the exact statement of the exercise. It is clear they want the students to relate the variation in the period with the variation on gravitational acceleration due to height change. But "loose 20s" might mean that the period increased by 20s, or that in the time it took to take the clock up the mountain the cumulative "delay" is 20s ("delay meaning" how many less cycles the clock in the mountain would make). It could also mean that it takes 20s for 2 identical pendulums (one in mountain, one below) to have equal position and momentum.

Comment: @rmhleo : I think the question meant that the second pendulum (i.e. a pendulum with a time period of 2 seconds) loses 20 seconds each day... I guess it means the pendulum is slower. I think the cause of it is change in $g$ but I am still confused

Comment: @Eliza, you are correct, the cause is the change of $g$. Maybe you are still confused because you are not familiar with Newton law for gravity $F_g = \frac{G*m_1*m_2}{r^2}$. Is this the case?

Comment: @rmhleo: I know this law, I was just confused about seconds being "lost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation:

If the pendulum has a period $\tau$ (2 seconds in this case) then the number of oscillations per day,$N$, is the number of seconds in a day divided by $\tau$:

$$ N = \frac{86400}{\tau} $$

If the pendulum loses $T$ seconds per day (20 seconds in this case) then the number of seconds lost per oscillation, $\Delta\tau$, is:

$$ \Delta\tau = \frac{T}{N} = \frac{T\tau}{86400} $$

And the period of the pendulum is therefore reduced to:

$$ \tau' = \tau - \Delta\tau = \tau\left(1 - \frac{T}{86400}\right) $$

Since the period of the pendulum is [related to the gravitational acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Period_of_oscillation) you can now calculate $g$ and therefore the change in distance from the centre of the Earth.

Comment: This is what the question wanted me to do. However, I want to be sure about one thing: when one says that the pendulum loses 20  seconds a day, does it mean that for the same $N$ number of oscillation in a day, the pendulum take 20 seconds more to finish?

Comment: @Eliza: as long as $T$ is much less than 86,400 there is little difference. If $T$ was a significant fraction of 86,400 then yes you'd probably want to get the question clarified.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the question;  specifically the "lost seconds per day"

A pendulum is used to regulate a clock;  in its original location, the clock keeps perfect time, as judged against some standard:  WWV time signal, chronometer, etc...

The clock is packed up, transported to a new location, set up and set running.  The clock is set to the correct time (say, midnight or $00:00:00.00$) by the same standard as above. When the standard says that the **next** midnight has arrived, the pendulum clock reads only $23:59:40$.

The pendulum has allowed the clock to mark off only $86,380$ seconds.  The pendulum is swinging slower than it did originally;  the period of the pendulum has increased, by a factor of $\frac{86400}{86380}$.

That said, other answers have detailed how to use this information to find the height of the mountain...

Comment: a really good explanation. Just one thing, does a pendulum show the time as a function of the number of complete oscillations?

Comment: Depends on the design of the clock.  Most mechanical clocks are a simple motor, gravity driven or spring driven, that spin gears to drive the two or three hands of the clock.  Somewhere in the gear train, at the escapement, the swing of the pendulum (or a balance wheel in a wrist watch) allows one tooth of the gear to move;  in some designs another tooth will move on the back swing.  In a neat bit of engineering, the gear being released give the pendulum a little push, to keep it swinging...